# Why is Will Ferrell's face pixelated in this Emmy Awards clip from Family Guy?

Tags: family-guy

Around minute 04:00 of "The Talented Mr. Stewie" (Family Guy, Season 19, Episode 2) there is a brief cutaway to the 70th Emmy Awards. Why is the face of the host (Will Ferrell) pixelated?

[image]

Here is the 4-seconds clip from Family Guy: https://streamable.com/opp0aj

and here is the original clip from the 70th Emmy Awards:

Comment: Hard to tell from a still frame, but is it actually censored with CGI, or just a blurry shot?  If it was an issue of not getting permission to use people's likenesses, I'd expect everyone to be censored in similar fashion.

Comment: I only know that the person censored is Will Ferrell  During the 70th Emmy Awards where  The Marvelous Mrs. Maisel won the Emmy for Outstanding Comedy Series

Comment: @Steve-O in the original video he is clearly visible so they did pixilate it for Family Guy

Comment: @Steve-O It is actually censored. Not a blurry frame.

Comment: Perhaps mouthed something obscene and it's easier to blur his whole face rather than just his mouth.

Comment: Maybe Will Ferrell doesn't like "Family Guy"? Maybe he refused permission for them to use his image?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I doubt Will Ferrell's permission is needed. The copyrights are of the Emmy Awards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making the presenter faceless draws more attention to the people winning the award, which is in line with what Stewie was saying.  Having an instantly recognizable Will Ferrell up there would have drawn attention to Will and people would be wondering why they weren't getting the joke.

Comment: Sorry, I was staring at Alex Borstein.  What was the joke, now?

Comment: Yeah, I think too that they blurred Ferrell's face because he was distracting from the joke. But I guess that's something they decided in post-production. Because it would had been much better just cutting the Emmy Awards clip differently, so that Ferrell was already giving the back to the audience. Blurred face is distracting too.